# Find the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of $\sin\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Essentially I have to solve the differential equation:
\begin{equation} \sin\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x} = \lambda f \tag{1}\end{equation}

**Attempt 1:** Differentiate $(1)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
f''\cos(f') =  f'' \sqrt{1-\sin^2f'} = f''\sqrt{1-\lambda^2f^2}= \lambda f'
\end{eqnarray*}

And here I am stuck having no idea how to solve this non-linear differential equation.

**Attempt 2:** Take $\arcsin$ on both sides of $(1)$
$$\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x} = \sin^{-1}(\lambda f)$$
Solving this differential equation,
$$x = \frac{\operatorname{Ci}(\sin^{-1}(\lambda f))}{\lambda} + C$$

Is it possible to express this in the form of $f=f(x)$? Is there any other method to approach this problem?

Comment: Since $f\mapsto\sin(df/dx)$ isn't linear, you might want $f\mapsto\sum_{n\ge0}\tfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\tfrac{d^{2n+1}}{dx^{2n+1}}f$. Then the problem is $f(x+i)-f(x-i)=2i\lambda f(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

From

$$
f''\cos(f')=\lambda f'\Rightarrow u'\cos(u)=\lambda u\Rightarrow u = \text{CosIntegral}^{(-1)}(c_1+\lambda  x)
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!! $u=\sin^{-1}(\lambda f) = \operatorname{Ci}^{-1}(\lambda x + c_1) \implies f = \frac{1}{\lambda}\sin(\operatorname{Ci}^{-1}(\lambda x+c_1))$. I had presumed something like $\operatorname{Ci}^{-1}(x)$ doesn't make sense.